# execute class files with packages?

Tags: java, .class-file

In general, how can one execute a `.class` file through powershell/command prompt that contains packages in it? I'm still having trouble with that.
Assume the file is `ClassFile.class`, with the package called `Pack` and the class file's location in `C:\Program Files\Folderhere\ClassFile.class`.

Comment: does the class have a `main`?

Comment: Well I do see "main method" in the code, so i assume so. Sorry, I am a big noob when it comes to Java.

Comment: Then you can just do `java ClassFile` without the `.class` extension. At least in linux. In windows I can't remember if the java path is available for execution from the command line easily.

Comment: It's giving me the `NoClassDefFoundError` error. I have my classpaths and paths all changed, but it still gives me the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the class is in a package called `Pack` then you'd do

```
java Pack.ClassFile
```

Have you copied the compiled code around at all, moving it from one directory to another? If you have, it's important to maintain the directory structure that it was originally compiled into.

If I was writing some code in a package and compiling and running it, these are the steps I'd take. Assume we've cd'd to a clean directory first.

```
mkdir Pack
vi Pack/ClassFile.java
javac Pack/ClassFile.java
java Pack.ClassFile
```

Comment: Nope, haven't changed any directories. I tried what you suggested and I got this message : `Could not find or load main class Pack.ClassFile`

Comment: OK - I've expanded the answer a bit so you can see the general steps that need to be taken to comile and run code in packages